# CK Editor - How to remove and add colors in Text Colors tab

Tags: ckeditor

I need to remove some of the ugly neon colors that are found within the Text Color tab in the CK Editor toolbar. If Possible I would also like to add some custom colors as well.

Please can anyone point me in the right direction.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it, thanks to alfonsoml at CKsource: It's explained in the config options: http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/src/plugins_colorbutton_plugin.js.html

The trick is to search for colorbutton and not Text color, which is why it's so hard to find :(